# conversion between decimal number and binary number in C

Tags: c, binary, decimal

I want to get pairs of bits from decimal number (e.g. 75 -> 0b01001011) and save them in separate variables. So for 75 I expect to get four variables with 1,0,2,3 values. I am looking for best performance solution.

Here is my test:

```
uint16_t k,kk,kkk,kkkk;
unsigned char a,b,c,d;
k=kk=kkk=kkkk = 75;
a = k & ~(0b11111100);
b = (kk & ~(0b11110011)) >> 2 ;
c = (kkk & ~(0b11001111)) >> 4;
d = (kkkk & ~(0b00111111)) >> 6;
```

Can you find better and faster solution? I mean, the disadvantage of this solution is, that I must to create copies of the original variable because it is changed every time I set one of the a,b,c,d variables.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "decimal number type". The representation is not part of the concept of a "number".

Comment: This question seems overly complex and confused. It sounds like you simply want to produce the base-4 digits of a number. Just keep dividing by 4 and compute the remainder.

Comment: Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_system

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question seems to about "Please write my code for me."

Answer (score 0):

This approach is cca 4xfaster:

```
uint16_t k;
unsigned char a,b,c,d;
k = 75;
a = k & 0b11;
b = (k & 0b1100) >> 2 ;
c = (k & 0b110000) >> 4;
d = (k & 0b11000000) >> 6;
```